# Couchbase Mobile 2.0 set Array in MutableDocument

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I have an object with an element which is a list and the `MutableDocument` has a `.setArray` method but this is expecting an instance of `com.couchbase.lite.Array`. 
How do I go about this to set my list and save the document.

This is how my model looks like

> private String signature;
>   private String comments;
>   private boolean isDraft;
>   public List ids;
>   public List fingers;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of complex types you will have to handle serializing them down into their primitives and creating an array that way.  So in the end you would have a mutable array object first and then add in dictionaries containing values that represent your objects (I don't know what 'Customer' and 'Bio' look like so I can't comment further).  It would probably be easier to create a method that will do that for you on each class that you want to serialize.  That way you can quickly and recursively create the objects for use in the database.